# Grouping twice by different criteria, same column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have data with the following columns:

```
OFFICER_ID, CLIENT_ID, SECURITY_CODE, POSITION_SIZE
```

and then per each row for instance:

```
officer1, client100, securityZYX, $100k,
officer2, client124, securityADF, $200k,
officer1, client130, securityARR, $150k,
officer4, client452, securityADF, $200k,
officer2, client124, securityARR, $500k,
officer7, client108, securityZYX, $223k, 
and so on.
```

As you see, each client has a single officer assigned to either buy o sell securities, but each client can have bought different securities.

Apart from ranking officers by total amount in US$ of securities held by their clients (which I've done) I need to create ranges of total client accounts by adding total securities held by client ID, for example, total securities held sum < $1million, between $1million and $3million and > $3 million.

I've tried:

```
SELECT officer_ID, SUM(position_size) as AUM
FROM trades
GROUP BY client_ID
HAVING AUM > 1000000 AND AUM < 3000000;
```

and I get a list of all officers appearing several times, no totals.

I'd need a simple:

```
Officer_ID | range < 1m | range 1m-3m | range > 3m
```

officer1, [total amount of client accounts with securities adding up < 1m totals], [total amount of client accounts with securities adding up between 1m and 3m totals], etc.

Please, would you point me in the right direction?

UPDATE

I modified Tim's suggested code and obtained the desired output:

```
SELECT
    OFFICER_ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN total < 1000000 THEN total END) AS "range < 1m",
    SUM(CASE WHEN total >= 1000000 AND total < 3000000 THEN total END) AS "range 1m-3m",
    SUM(CASE WHEN total >= 3000000 THEN total END) AS "range > 3m"
FROM
(
    SELECT OFFICER_ID, CLIENT_ID, SUM(POSITION_SIZE) AS total
    FROM trades
    GROUP BY OFFICER_ID, CLIENT_ID
) t
GROUP BY
    OFFICER_ID;
```

Too kind, Tim, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can try aggregating twice, first by both officer and client, to get the client totals, and a second time by officer alone, to get the counts:

```
SELECT
    OFFICER_ID,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN total < 1000000 THEN 1 END) AS "range < 1m",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN total >= 1000000 AND total < 3000000 THEN 1 END) AS "range 1m-3m",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN total >= 3000000 THEN 1 END) AS "range > 3m"
FROM
(
    SELECT OFFICER_ID, CLIENT_ID, SUM(POSITION_SIZE) AS total
    FROM trades
    GROUP BY OFFICER_ID, CLIENT_ID
) t
GROUP BY
    OFFICER_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, Tim, apologies for the delayed response.

I'm now counting ocurences of client accounts per range, but I'd need to retrieve not how many accounts are there in each segment, but rather the total account value of client accounts per segment for each officer, for example:

Officer_ID | range < 1m | range 1m-3m | range > 3m
officer1, $4m, $20m, $10m
officer1, $2m, $0, $20m

and so on. Again, help is much appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and show **clear** sample input data and the output you expect.